# Dell DRAC -- idracadm7 find user by username

Tags: drac

So for years we've been using the `idracadm7` command to manage a couple of DRAC account passwords (for example, `sam`):

```
INDEX=`idracadm7 -r dracIP -u root -p rootpasswd getconfig -u sam | grep Index | cut -d= -f2`
idracadm7 -r dracIP -u root -p rootpassword config -i $INDEX -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword sampassword
```

And it works, but I get these warnings:

```
RAC1168: The RACADM "getconfig" command will be deprecated in a
future version of iDRAC firmware. Run the RACADM
"racadm get" command to retrieve the iDRAC configuration parameters.
For more information on the get command, run the RACADM command
"racadm help get".

RAC1169: The RACADM "config" command will be deprecated in a
future version of iDRAC firmware. Run the RACADM
"racadm set" command to configure the iDRAC configuration parameters.
For more information on the set command, run the RACADM command
"racadm help set".
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to use the `get` subcommand to replace the `getconfig` subcommand.  And while I can see how to find a user by index number

```
idracadm7 -r dracIP -u root -p rootpassword get iDRAC.Users.3.UserName | grep UserName=
UserName=sam
```

I cannot find any way to find the index number of the user named `sam` like I can with the `getconfig -u` command.

Am I missing it somewhere?